# clang 14.0.0 floating point optimizations

Tags: c, optimization, floating-point, clang

I was executing the code from this question: [Why is the output of the following code not zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73967507/why-is-the-output-of-the-following-code-not-zero)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    double A = 373737.0;
    double B;

    B = A*A*A + 0.37/A - A*A*A - 0.37/A;
    printf("The value of B is %f.\n", B);
}
```

Every mainstream x86 compiler with every optimization setting gives output `-0.000001`. I get that with the current clang 15.0.0 when I use `-O0` as well.

*However*, compiling with clang beyond version 14.0.0 with `-O1` to `-O3` gives the output `-1.000001`. Why is this happening? Is this a known bug?

Godbolt for your convenience: https://godbolt.org/z/M5j3fGhWf

Comment: It looks like it is a rounding issue in Clang at first glance. Certainly a bug indeed since it breaks the IEEE-754 rules (I cannot produce this result even with other rounding methods so far).

Comment: Well I'm not sure if it's a known and reported bug or not. If it isn't, then feel free to report it. Personally I gave up on clang long time ago so I don't really care about reporting bugs.

Comment: @rici Speculation: the result of `1.0` for `A*A*A - A*A*A` is the result you'd get if you computed it as `fms(A*A, A, (A*A)*A)` where `fms` is fused multiply-subtract.

Comment: @MarkDickinson: OK, you were definitely right (about fused-multiply-add), and apparently I was wrong (about it being a bug). It's a "feature". Standard-C actually gives the translator license to use fused-multiply-add (or any other fused operation); in a fused `a*b+c` (or `a*b-c`, which is just an instance of the same), `a*b+c` is computed exactly and then rounded. However, the intermediate values `a`, `b`, and `c` may have been rounded prior to the fused operation, which is what happens here. Writing an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a pretty deep rabbit hole, and I don't know if I've explored all of its twists and turns yet. But here's a first draft of an answer; suggestions for improvement are welcome.

At its core, the culprit is the so-called "fused multiply-add" (or, in this case, a fused multiply-subtract). [Fused multiply-add](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiply%E2%80%93accumulate_operation) is a single instruction which computes `a*b+c` in a single step. This can significantly speed up certain computations (such as dot products and polynomials using Horner's rule). It was added to [Intel's x86 instruction set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FMA_instruction_set) in about 2013 (Haswell); a similar instruction was added to AMD chips a year earlier. But the idea is not new; high-end processors have included such instructions at least since 1990 (with IBM's POWER1 processor).

Because the result of the fused operation is only once (instead of being rounded twice after the multiply and again after the add), it often produces more accurate results. Unfortunately, there are cases where it produces less accurate results, and this is one of them; it's triggered by the computation of `a*b-c` where `a*b` and `c` are very similar, and `c` was previously rounded. [Note 1] To see the problem in action, it's useful to reduce the code to a minimum, whose result is at least surprising:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void) {
    double A = 373737.0;
    printf("A*A*A - A*A*A is %f.\n", A*A*A - A*A*A);
    return 0;
}
```

With clang since v14.0.0, that prints out 1.000000. [Note 2] The result is 1 (rather than -1) because the expression `A*A*A - A*A*A` is turned into a fused multiply-subtract of `A*A`, `A`, and `A*A*A`. Now, 373737³ is exactly 52203339425426553, a 56-bit number. Since `double` on an x86 platform allows only 53 significant bits, that needs to be rounded to the nearest representable value, which is 52203339425426552. In the fused operation, 373737² * 373737 is computed exactly, and then the rounded value of 373737³ is subtracted, leaving 1.

In the original program, the computation was (approximately) 373737³ + 1e-6 - 373737³ - 1e-6. In this computation, 373737³ + 1e-6 is first computed (using FMA) and rounded, which again is 52203339425426552; adding 1e-6 has no effect on the rounded sum. Then a fused negated-multiply-add is performed, adding 52203339425426552 and the precise negated product of 373737² and 373737 (-52203339425426553); the result is exactly `-1`. Finally, 1e-6 is subtracted, leading to the observed result of `-1.000001`.

That's the essence of what Goldberg calls "catastrophic cancellation" (See note 1 if you haven't already read it); the subtraction of two very similar values cancels out all significance.

(On the other hand, with some care you can use the fact that the multiplication in the fused operation was not rounded in order to produce a more accurate final result, using an algorithm due to the Canadian mathematician [William Kahan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Kahan), primary architect of the IEEE-754 standards. See, for example, [this enlightening answer by @njuffa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50065711/1566221) on how to accurately compute quadratic roots when b² is close to 4ac.)

So what changed with Clang v14.0.0? Both Clang and GCC have an option which controls whether FMA is used: `-ffp-contract`. (In the C standard, FMA is one of the examples of "contracted operations", and this option controls all such operations.) That option has three possible values: `off`, `on` and `fast`. `off` always means that the compiler will not fuse multiplies and adds when compiling expressions. (It will still compile the `fma` function into an FMA opcode, if that opcode is available on the target machine.) Up until v13.0.0, `off` was the default for Clang; with v14.0.0, [the default was changed to `on`](https://releases.llvm.org/14.0.0/tools/clang/docs/ReleaseNotes.html#floating-point-support-in-clang), which allows fusing multiply and add in the same expression. Since then, Clang will, by default, emit FMA instructions if the target architecture implements them. More relevantly for this question, it will also emulate FMA for constant computations performed at compile-time.

Although GCC has the same option, the semantics are somewhat different. As far as I know, GCC does not emulate FMA for compile-time computations. Furthermore, GCC interprets `-ffp-contract=on` as being the same as `-ffp-contract=off` (!), and its default is `-ffp-contract=fast`. The `fast` setting allows contracted operations not only within expressions (which is allowed by standard C) but also in computations which span different expressions. However, for this particular computation, GCC's optimizer prefers to save and reuse the value of the common subexpression `A*A*A`, rather than emitting an FMA. [Note 3]

Clang also allows `-ffp-contract=fast`, with approximately the same semantics as GCC, but the result of specifying that option is that the constant folder cannot emulate FMA. [Note 4]

The C standard actually defines a portable mechanism to control the use of contracted operations: the `#pragma STDC FP_CONTRACT`, with possible values `ON`, `OFF` and `DEFAULT`. `OFF` is required to suppress emission of FMA operations, but the standard places no other restriction; the default can be `ON` and `OFF`, and `ON` is not required to do anything in particular. However, GCC does not implement this pragma (as of GCC v12), so it's not as portable as one might wish. (Clang does implement, though.)

Although, as this question shows, the use of fused multiply-add can have surprising results, and it's easy to fall into the trap of assuming that such results are compiler bugs, it's pretty clear that the standard does intend that compilers are free to use FMA and other contracted operations, as long as there is a way of turning the feature off, as indicated in §6.5 paragraph 8, whose wording has not changed since C99:

> A floating expression may be contracted, that is, evaluated as though it were a single operation, thereby omitting rounding errors implied by the source code and the expression evaluation method. The `FP_CONTRACT` pragma in `<math.h>` provides a way to disallow contracted expressions. Otherwise, whether and how expressions are contracted is implementation-defined.

The clause is accompanied by this footnote:

> This license is specifically intended to allow implementations to exploit fast machine instructions that combine multiple C operators. As contractions potentially undermine predictability, and can even decrease accuracy for containing expressions, their use needs to be well-defined and clearly documented.

It has been argued that the requirements in Appendix F for IEC-559 compliance (usually described as IEEE-754/854) override the licence explicitly mentioned above, but I don't find this argument convincing. First, §6.5, as cited above, is pretty clear. Second, Appendix F also contemplates contracted expressions in §F.7:

> A contracted expression is correctly rounded (once) and treats infinities, NaNs, signed zeros, subnormals, and the rounding directions in a manner consistent with the basic arithmetic operations covered by IEC 60559.

Third, IEEE-754 (2008, Note 5) is explicit in allowing implementations to implement contracted operations, as long as they provide a way to turn it off:

> A language standard should require that by default, when no optimizations are enabled and no alternate exception handling is enabled, language implementations preserve the literal meaning of the source code.
> …
> A language standard should also define, and require implementations to provide, attributes that allow and disallow value-changing optimizations, separately or collectively, for a block. These optimizations might include, but are not limited to:
>
> - Applying the associative or distributive laws.
> - Synthesis of a `fusedMultiplyAdd operation` from a multiplication and an addition.
>   …

I say all that with a certain pain, since I was also pretty sure that this behaviour was buggy. The unpredictability of application of FMA seems less than ideal. On the other hand, the standard defines the `fma` function, which should (and normally does) get compiled in-line into an appropriate machine instruction, and there are mechanisms to require compilers not to issue contracted expressions unless asked to explicitly, which I'm definitely going to consider using with more consistency.

#### Notes

1. This is the scenario described as "catastrophic cancellation" by David Goldberg in the essay [*What every computer scientist should know about floating point arithmetic*](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html), which is inevitably cited by any discussion of a floating-point quirk. By "cancellation", Goldberg means that significant digits are cancelled out by the subtraction, potentially leaving only digits within the error bounds.
2. At least, if you have the right compiler options specified. With default compiler options, you'll get 0.

   As noted in the OP, the odd result doesn't happen with the default compiler settings. That's because the default is no optimisations. With any optimisation enabled, Clang will fold constant expressions at compile time, and the constant folder *emulates* fused multiply-add. Without optimisation, the computation is done at run-time, and by default, Clang doesn't emit FMA instructions because they are not available on all supported x86 chips. You need to specify `-mfma` (or some other similar target selector) to indicate that the target architecture includes the FMA instruction set in order to see FMA instructions in the compiled binary.
3. I don't know whether GCC's constant folder emulates FMA; if I figure that out later, I'll edit this paragraph.
4. The reason that `-ffp-contract=fast` suppresses FMA in the constant folder is explained by LLVM committer Andy Kaylor in a [comment to bug 54927](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/54927#issuecomment-1104230123).
5. I don't have a copy of the later versions, but I suspect the essence hasn't changed.

Comment: Nice answer. I might not understand all of it, since I'm still not entirely convinced that it isn't a bug. `-O0 -ffp-contract=on` gives `0.000000.` The optimization level alone changes the result. Supposedly because it doesn't use FMA with optimizations disabled? How could we tell? It's also hard to tell what the compiler is actually doing, because the whole calculation goes on "off screen" and we're just handed a pre-calculated number in the assembly. Similarly if I move the calculation inside a function and force no inlining, then `-O3 -ffp-contract=on` gives result `0.000000` as well.

Comment: @lundin: I don't think there's a relationship between optimisation level and FMA. If you specify `-O0`, clang doesn't fold constants, so the computation is done at runtime. But clang won't emit FMA in compiled code unless you specify a target which implements the instructions. I think Gcc is the same. Try `-mfma`. (That also applies to your last sentence.)

Comment: I think I need to rewrite this answer to make the above clearer, since it is obviously being missed by readers.

Comment: Ah yeah I see. If I force it to use FMA in the binary with the option you mention, then it does generate different fp instructions in the binary itself, no matter optimization level. As illustrated here: https://godbolt.org/z/Pjjo8snss in the disassembly of `func` with or without `-mfma`. `-O3 -ffp-contract=on -mfma` gives the same result as `-O0 -ffp-contract=on -mfma`.

Comment: @lundin: Yup. I think it would be more accurate to say that `-mfma` *allows* the use of FMA ops. The option declares that the target machine has FMA opcodes (Haswell or more recent in the case of Intel x86).