# Clang fused multiply-add depends on constancy of expression arguments

Tags: c, optimization, floating-point, clang, fma

As indicated in the answer to [clang 14.0.0 floating point optimizations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73985098/clang-14-0-0-floating-point-optimizations), Clang since version 14 applies fused multiply add (FMA) instructions even for constant computations performed at compile-time.

At the same time, one can observe that the result depends on formal constancy of expression arguments:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    const float A = 2.1f;
    const float B = 0.1f;
          float C = 0.1f;
    float V = A * B - A * B;
    float W = A * C - A * C;
    printf( "%g %g", V, W );
}
```

In Clang the program prints `0 1.49011e-10`, online demo: https://godbolt.org/z/a3fcYG7ob

From the assembly code, it can be seen that both `V` and `W` are evaluated in compile-time. Is there some rule that dictates that only `W` can be evaluated using FMA instruction?

Adding `-mno-fma` command line option for disabling FMA instruction does not change anything in the result.

Comment: Also related: [Why does C++ rounding behavior (for compile-time constants) change if math is moved to an inline function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76214764) re: effect of const or constexpr on FP-contraction (to FMA) vs. constant-propagation.  Also [clang 14.0.0 floating point optimizations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73985098)

Comment: don't think this is what you want, but it seems you can force compile usage of FMA by explicitly using it:  https://godbolt.org/z/adjxYr19K