# What are the implications of constexpr floating-point math?

Tags: c++, floating-point, constexpr, c++23, c++26

Since C++11, we are able to do floating point math at compile time. C++23 and C++26 added `constexpr` to some functions, but not to all.

`constexpr` floating point math is weird in general, because the results aren't perfectly accurate. However, `constexpr` code is supposed to always deliver consistent results. How does C++ approach this issue?

#### Questions

- How does `constexpr` floating point math work?

  - Are the results the same for all compilers?
  - Are the results the same between compile-time and runtime for the same compiler?
- Why are some functions `constexpr`, but others not (like `std::nearbyint`)

Comment: Answers: no, no, give it time.

Comment: The biggest burden must be for cross-compilers having to `constexpr` a different floating point architecture.

Comment: Some nice example how adding `const` (or `constexpr`) changes the result: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75859098/7325599

Answer (score 35, accepted):

C++ imposes very few restrictions on the behavior of `float` and other floating-point types. This can lead to possible inconsistencies in the results, both between compilers, and between runtime/compile-time evaluation by the same compiler. Here is the tl;dr on it:

|  | At runtime | In constant expressions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Floating-point errors, like division by zero** | UB, but compilers may support silent errors through NaN as an extension | UB in a constant expression results in a compiler error |
| **Rounded operations, like `10.0 / 3.0`** | Rounding mode controlled through floating-point environment; results may vary | Rounding is implementation-defined, results can differ from runtime |
| **Semantics changes through `-ffast-math` and other compiler optimizations** | Results can become less precise or more precise as a result; IEEE-754 conformance is broken | No effect in practice; at most implementation-defined effect |
| **Calls to math functions** | Same handling of errors and rounding as arithmetic with `+` and `*` | Some `constexpr` since C++23, some `constexpr` since C++26, with some errors disallowed at compile-time |

### Floating-Point Errors

Some operations can fail, such as division by zero. The C++ standard says:

> If the second operand of / or % is zero the behavior is undefined.

- [[expr.mul]/4](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.mul#4)

In constant expressions, this is respected, and so it's not possible to produce NaN through operations or raise [`FE_DIVBYZERO`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv/FE_exceptions) at compile time.

No exception is made for floating point numbers. However, when `std::numeric_limits<float>::is_iec559()` is `true`, most compilers will have IEEE-754 compliance as an extension. For example, division by zero is allowed and produces infinity or NaN depending on the operands.

### Rounding Modes

C++ has always allowed differences between compile-time results and runtime results.
For example, you can evaluate:

```cpp
double x = 10.0f / 3.0;
constexpr double y = 10.0 / 3.0;
assert(x == y); // might fail
```

The result might not always be the same, because the floating point environment can only be changed at runtime, and thus the rounding mode can be altered.

C++'s approach is to make the effect of the floating point environment implementation-defined. It gives you no portable way to control it (and thus rounding) in constant expressions.

> If the [`FENVC_ACCESS`] pragma is used to enable control over the floating-point environment, this document does not specify the effect on floating-point evaluation in constant expressions.

- [[cfenv.syn]/Note 1](https://eel.is/c++draft/cfenv.syn#note-1)

### Compiler Optimizations

Firstly, compilers can be eager to optimize your code, even if it changes its meaning. For example, GCC will optimize away this call:

```cpp
// No call to sqrt thanks to constant folding.
// This ignores the fact that this is a runtime evaluation, and would normally be impacted
// by the floating point environment at runtime.
const float x = std::sqrt(2);
```

The semantics change even more with flags like `-ffast-math` which allows the compiler to reorder and optimize operations in a way that is not IEEE-754 compliant. For example:

```cpp
float big() { return 1e20f;}

int main() {
    std::cout << big() + 3.14f - big();
}
```

For IEEE-754 floating point numbers, addition and subtraction are not commutative. We cannot optimize this to: `(big() - big()) + 3.14f`. The result will be `0`, because `3.14f` is too small to make any change to `big()` when added, due to lack of precision. However, with `-ffast-math` enabled, the result can be `3.14f`.

### Mathematical Functions

There can be runtime differences to constant expressions for all operations, and that includes calls made to mathematical functions. `std::sqrt(2)` at compile-time might not be the same as `std::sqrt(2)` at runtime. However, this issue is not unique to math functions. You can put these functions into the following categories:

##### No FPENV Dependence / Very Weak Dependence (`constexpr` since C++23) [[P05333r9]](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p0533r9.pdf)

Some functions are completely independent of the floating-point environment, or they simply cannot fail, such as:

- `std::ceil` (round to next greater number)
- `std::fmax` (maximum of two numbers)
- `std::signbit` (obtains the sign bit of a floating-point number)

Furthermore, there are functions like `std::fma` which just combine two floating point operations. These are no more problematic than `+` and `*` at compile-time. The behavior is is the same as calling these math functions in C (see [C23 Standard, Annex F.8.4](https://www.iso-9899.info/n3047.html#F.8.4)), however, it is not a constant expression in C++ if exceptions other than `FE_INEXACT` are raised, `errno` is set, etc (see [[library.c]/3](https://eel.is/c++draft/library.c#3)).

##### Weak FPENV Dependence (`constexpr` since C++26) [[P1383r0]](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1383r0.pdf)

Other functions are dependent on the floating point environment, such as `std::sqrt` or `std::sin`. However, this dependence is called *weak*, because it's not explicitly stated, and it only exists because floating-point math is inherently imprecise.

It would be arbitrary to allow `+` and `*` at compile-time, but not math functions which have the exact same issues.

##### Mathematical Special Functions (not `constexpr` yet, possibly in the future)

[[P1383r0]](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1383r0.pdf) deemed it *too ambitious* to add `constexpr` to for [*mathematical special functions*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/special_functions), such as:

- `std::beta`
- `std::riemann_zeta`
- and many more ...

##### Strong FPENV Dependence (not `constexpr` yet, possibly never)

Some functions like `std::nearbyint` are explicitly stated to use the current rounding mode in the standard.
This is problematic, because you cannot control the floating-point environment at compile time using standard means.
Functions like `std::nearbyint` aren't `constexpr`, and possibly never will be.

### Conclusion

In summary, there are many challenges facing the standard committee and compiler developers when dealing with `constexpr` math. It has taken decades of discussion to lift some restrictions on `constexpr` math functions, but we are finally here. The restrictions have ranged from arbitrary in the case of `std::fabs`, to necessary in the case of `std::nearbyint`.

We are likely to see further restrictions lifted in the future, at least for *mathematical special functions*.

Comment: `const` or `constexpr` can sometimes influence optimization choices (and compile-time eval strategy and results), like order of constant-propagation vs. FP contraction to FMA, as in [Clang fused multiply-add depends on constancy of expression arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75859098) and [Why does C++ rounding behavior (for compile-time constants) change if math is moved to an inline function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76214764).

Comment: Is `std::numeric_limits<float>::is_iec559()` supposed to yield `true` on implementations that don't process `1.0f/0.0f` in a manner consistent with IEC559, i.e. by yielding NaN?

Comment: @supercat it's not meant to; the value is true iff the implementation adheres to IEC 60559. See https://eel.is/c++draft/numeric.limits.members#53. However, it's possible that even though this value is true, either the hardware doesn't implement all operations with perfect compliance, or the math libraries don't give the most accurate result as required. See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Floating-point-implementation.html for example; the GCC docs acknowledge that a system library might not conform, and this is not up to the compiler, even though `is_iec559` is a compile-time constant.

Answer (score 9):

Jan Schultke already gave an excellent answer, I just want to address some potential misunderstanding:

## Compile time is not the same as `constexpr`

> Since C++11, we are able to do floating point math at compile time.

That's not true. Compilers have been able to do compile time math for a much longer time, and nothing in older versions of C++ has prevented that. GCC and Clang will happily do a compile time floating point division without `constexpr`, even with `-std=c++98 -O0`.

Also, it's good to keep in mind that the only requirement for [`constepxr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) is that “it is *possible* to evaluate the value of the function or variable at compile time.” It is still perfectly fine for the compiler to emit instructions to do the math at runtime.

Comment: The question should probably be extended a bit into `consteval`, `constinit` and similar territory.