# Compare the computation speed of (a+b)*c and a*c+b*c

Tags: c, computation-theory, time-estimation

I've just learned that additive operation is faster than multiplicative operation in C. Therefore, I'm curious whether `(a+b)*c` would be calculated faster than `a*c+b*c` ?

Comment: Just to complicate things: modern processors may do the 2 multiplications *in parallel*.

Comment: On what CPU? What compiler and compilation flags? Integer or floating point operations?

Comment: *I've just learned that additive operation is faster than multiplicative operation in C.*  That might even be true.  Then again, it might not.  Saying something like "X is faster than Y" has almost no meaning when CPUs are deeply-pipelined devices that run multiple instructions in parallel.  Don't worry about microoptimizations like this at all.  You'll almost never have any real effect on processing speed, and any effect you have has a good chance of making things worse.

Comment: @ScottHunter Except there is just 1 multiplication once optimized :)

Comment: @Lundin Pedantically, `a*c+b*c` better not be optimized to `(a+b)*c`  ;-)

Comment: @AndrewHenle Not sure what you mean. That optimization is exactly what happened when I tried it on gcc.

Comment: @Lundin `(a+b)*c` can produce different results than `a*c+b*c`.  At least for floating-point calculations, such an optimization shouldn't be done.  If the types were all unsigned integer types so overflow couldn't happen and UB invoked, the different results could also apply if the arguments were different sizes such as `uint8_t a,b; uint32_t c;`.  Signed-integer operations?  Since overflow invokes UB in that case, maybe the optimization is allowed?

Comment: @AndrewHenle Ah yeah I guess the OP didn't specify what type this is for, I just assumed plain old integer. Floating point is another story entirely though, check out [this oddity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73985098/clang-14-0-0-floating-point-optimizations) as one example.

Answer (score 6):

> I've just learned that additive operation is faster than multiplicative operation in C

That's nonsense. There is nothing in the C language itself that affects this. Which is faster depends entirely on the instruction set (ISA) provided by the CPU.

> Therefore, I'm curious whether `(a+b)*c` would be calculated faster than `a*c+b*c`

It is very likely that the optimizing compiler will generate the same machine code no matter which of those versions you write in the C code. Try out this code:

```
int add1 (int a, int b, int c)
{
  return (a+b)*c;
}

int add2 (int a, int b, int c)
{
  return a*c+b*c;
}
```

On `gcc -O3` 13.1 for x86_x64 I get 100% equivalent assembler code for both versions:

```
add1:
    lea     eax, [rdi+rsi]
    imul    eax, edx
    ret
add2:
    lea     eax, [rsi+rdi]
    imul    eax, edx
    ret
```

Comment: extra kudos for the grumpy. I like grumpy.

Comment: @MikeNakis I bet you just love SO then :)

Comment: Not particularly, because grumpiness is generally frowned upon, (I have tried to be grumpy, my comments get deleted.) But I agree that if it was free for all grumpy then it would not be nearly as useful. So. There's that.

Comment: @MikeNakis It's actually a big problem that people today read all manner of strange things into one's written text and assume the worst unless you add at least 5 emojis at the end...

Comment: Hi @Lundin Could you please guide me in learning assembly language. I'm very interested but cannot find a proper path and resources

Comment: @RituparnaWarwatkar Check out the [assembler tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/assembly/info) here on SO - lots of good resources there.

Comment: @Lundin Thank you Sir !
Also I had a doubt, I have a laptop that runs on AMD ryzen 5 CPU... If we write programs in assembly language of my CPU, will I be able to run that program on the bare metal without any operating system ? Is that possible ?. Lets say just a simple program that takes input 2 numbers and adds them and displays output.

Comment: Re "*It is very likely that the optimizing compiler will generate the same machine code*", For integers, quite possibly. But for floats? Compilers don't tend to reorganize float operations because the order is significant because of precision loss. For example, there's a flag for gcc to let it do those rearrangements (whose name I forget).

Comment: @ikegami Float operations should yield a consistent result, so these rearrangements might be not standard compliant. You are probably talking about [`-ffast-math`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420665/what-does-gccs-ffast-math-actually-do)

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! I was taught that multiplication like`a * b` is actually adding `a` for `b` times so it's slower than additive operation. Is it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to know for sure is to measure directly. You can look at the machine code, but that doesn't necessarily tell you how things will be processed; your system may execute operations in parallel.

Write up both versions, instrument the code to gather statistics (either through a profiler or manually), then run the computations several million times.